# PyTorch CUDA vs Numpy for arithmetic operations? Fastest?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, gpu, pytorch

I performed element-wise multiplication using Torch with GPU support and Numpy using the functions below and found that Numpy loops faster than Torch which shouldn't be the case, I doubt.

I want to know how to perform general arithmetic operations with Torch using GPU.

**Note:** I ran these code snippets in Google Colab notebook

**Define the default tensor type to enable global GPU flag**

```
torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor if 
                              torch.cuda.is_available() else 
                              torch.FloatTensor)
```

**Initialize Torch variables**

```
x = torch.Tensor(200, 100)  # Is FloatTensor
y = torch.Tensor(200,100)
```

**Function in question**

```
def mul(d,f):
    g = torch.mul(d,f).cuda()  # I explicitly called cuda() which is not necessary
    return g
```

When call the function above as 
`%timeit mul(x,y)`

**Returns:**

> The slowest run took 10.22 times longer than the fastest. This could
>   mean hat   an intermediate result is being cached.  10000 loops, best
>   of 3: 50.1 µs per loop

Now trial with numpy,

Used the same values from torch variables

```
x_ = x.data.cpu().numpy()
y_ = y.data.cpu().numpy()
```

```
def mul_(d,f):
    g = d*f
    return g
```

`%timeit mul_(x_,y_)`

**Returns**

> The slowest run took 12.10 times longer than the fastest. This could
>   mean that an intermediate result is being cached.  100000 loops, best
>   of 3: 7.73 µs per loop

Needs some help to understand GPU enabled Torch operations.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### GPU operations have to additionally get memory to/from the GPU

The problem is that your GPU operation always has to put the input on the GPU memory, and
then retrieve the results from there, *which is a quite costly operation*.

NumPy, on the other hand, directly processes the data from the CPU/main memory, so there is almost no delay here. Additionally, your matrices are extremely small, so even in the best-case scenario, there should only be a minute difference.

This is also partially the reason why you use mini-batches when training on a GPU in neural networks: Instead of having several extremely small operations, you now have "one big bulk" of numbers that you can process in parallel. 
[Also note that GPU clock speeds are generally way lower than CPU clocks](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/33pors/eli5why_are_gpu_clock_speeds_soo_much_lower_than/), so the GPU only really shines because it has *way more cores*. If your matrix does not utilize all of them fully, you are also likely to see a faster result on your CPU.

**TL;DR:** *If your matrix is big enough, you will eventually see a speed-up in `CUDA` than Numpy, even with the additional cost of the GPU transfer.*

Comment: Thanks, also i found similar question from the torch discussion forum

Comment: Feel free to share a link in the comments, so others know directly about the thing you are talking about.

Comment: Here is the link that discusses similar problem https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1630

Comment: I think the TL;DR note downplays too much the massive performance boost that GPU's can bring. For example, if you have a 2-D or 3-D grid where you need to perform (elementwise) operations, Pytorch-CUDA can be hundeds of times faster than Numpy, or even compiled C/FORTRAN code. I have tested this dozens of times during my PhD.

Comment: For elementwise operations, Numpy won't even utilize multithreading, which makes it extremely slow, especially for large arrays.

Comment: Both of these comments do not acknowledge that OP actually has said their code is running *slower* when using NumPy. I agree that GPU utilization is hugely beneficial - but only in those cases where it can actually accelerate something.