# When not to use Tensors

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have been using PyTorch for a while now and am making a general RL framework. I am running into the question of whether to use np.arrays or tensors.

When would you not want to use tensors when available? What would make you choose numpy over pytorch? Obviously tensors are important for ML models, but what if you want to just do basic image processing or list manipulation?

I am tempted to use Tensors whenever possible but do not know of any pitfalls. (graph confusion? memory leaks??)

For example, I have a basic unfinished code snippet of collecting actions for an env, not sure whether to stick with numpy or not.

```py
@dataclass
class Action(object):
    """
    Handles actions, action space, and value verification.
    """
    taken_action: np.array
    raw_action: np.array
    n_possible_values: int
    action_space: gym.Space

    def __post_init__(self):
        if type(self.taken_action) is not np.array: taken_action = np.array([self.taken_action])

@pytest.mark.parametrize("env", sorted([env.id for env in gym.envs.registry.all()]))
def test_action_data_structure(env):
    try:
        init_env = gym.make(env)
    except error.DependencyNotInstalled as e:
        print(e)
        return

    taken_action = init_env.action_space.sample()
    raw_action = np.random.rand(init_env.action_space.n)
    state, reward, done, info = init_env.step(taken_action)

    action_dataclass = Action(taken_action=taken_action, raw_action=raw_action,
                              n_possible_values=init_env.action_space.n, action_space=init_env.action_space)
```

Comment: My impression had been that pytorch is a full replacement for numpy. If you mix numpy with pytorch, the resulting code might not run on a GPU. Is that not correct? (Admittedly, I'm new to pytorch, so I'm probably way off the mark.)

Comment: I believe you're correct, which I why I am so curious why I would ever use numpy. The only super obvious thing I can think of is that torch is an insane dependency, but I have seen ML repos mix torch and numpy so what do I know

Comment: In RL your environment will almost always not be able to handle or understand tensors and will expect numpy arrays. So typically right before you send your action to the environment you will convert it to a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is it depends. There is a tradeoff between speed and clarity when you debug your code. In case your matrices are huge you can jump between numpy and pytorch tensor from the reason the GPU will run the operations much faster than the delay that the conversion did. So it is tough to say where the threshold (of the dataset size) lies. I would try some simple operations to compare the options and then decide the best method that works for you.

In addition, I suggest you read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52530491/5106245)
and also this [blog post](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/how-pytorch-will-replace-numpy-2df48427f56d)