# Translate lots of text with transformers (huggingface)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, torch, huggingface-transformers

I need to translate a lot of small texts (tweets) with Transformers (Huggingface).

This is a slow process because of the amount of texts that I actually have.

This is my current code:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM
import torch,tensorflow 
device = "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-es-en")
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-es-n").to(device)

def translate(text):
    tokenized_text = tokenizer([text], return_tensors='pt').to(device)
    return tokenizer.batch_decode(model.generate(**tokenized_text), special_tokens=True)[0]

print(translate("Hola Mundo"))

tweets_es['tweet'] = tweets_es['tweet'].map(lambda x: translate(x))
```

I use a Dask dataframe and when it comes to compute it is a really long process (days..)

I also tried to run it into a Google Colab notebook and, of course, in both environments I made sure that I've been using the GPU to compute it.

I've been thinking in run the code in any cloud alternative (GCP, AWS...) but as it is a personal project I would like it to be free and also, I'm not sure which is the best alternative or even if the cloud is the best option I have.

Anybody facing a similar problem? options? comments?

Kind regards

Update: does BatchEncoding fit this purpose? I was reading online and I don't know if maybe it speeds up the translation

Comment: Unfortunately I think this is not going to give you a clear answer, which is why I'm voting to close. However, I might want to suggest batching your tweets before translating them, as [the overhead of memory transfer can be quite costly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526082/pytorch-cuda-vs-numpy-for-arithmetic-operations-fastest/52530491#52530491) (disclaimer: Another answer by myself).

Comment: Hello, were you able to solve your problem? I have the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no news on this. Also, as the input of the tokenizer function is a list, I tried to translate the tweets in block but it is a very memory intensive model and this causes that I can't translate more than 10 tweets at a time on my local machine (1650Ti). This also does not lead to superior performance (in time) according to the tests I have done.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that might result in a more agile translation is to limit the tokenizer from doing such a "deep" translation (max_lenght, padding....) with the associated consequence of not having such an accurate translation. 
https://huggingface.co/course/chapter2/6?fw=pt
Also, I didn't explore if it is possible to run this kind of models distributively on a cluster of gpus or they can't be parallelised...